# Bootstrap modal form labels

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with bootstrap modal form. I want the label of input to be on top of the input, not in front of it. If i make window smaller then the label jumps on top as you can see on

[image: picture].

If I make screen full width it jumps next to the inputs:
[image: full-width]

I am not very familiar with bootstrap grid system so I don't know how to set this up. Help is well appreciated.
This is html of my modal body:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="error-div">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">
          <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="exam_number">Number</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="exam_number" name="exam_number">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">File</label><br>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input  name="exam_file" type="file" accept="*" multiple required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            </div>
          </div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clear grid classes col-sm-2 & col-sm-10.
or 
you can changing col-sm-10 to col-sm-12.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class "control-group" and "controls" to adjust.

Something like:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="error-div">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">
      <label class="control-label" for="exam_number">Number</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select class="col-sm-10" id="exam_number" name="exam_number">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">File</label><br>
          <input  name="exam_file" type="file" accept="*" multiple required>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: great. jus thow would i horizontally center input as it goes left?

Comment: are you talking about the file input?